# Git how to get changed filenames from specific commits on a branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-log

Please help me on this.

I need to work like diff in bitbucket.

[image]

I need to know how to accomplish this with git command.

Thanks in advance.

Nathan.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to get that stats on the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git log --stat` if you want to see the files that changed in last commit:

```
git log --stat -1
```

**example output**

```
Author: Chris Maes <chris.maes@macq.eu>
Date:   Fri Oct 24 16:45:44 2014 +0200

    commit comment

 file1               | 7 +++++--
 file2               | 2 ++
 2 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

now you can do the same if you have the hash of your commit:

```
git log --stat hash -1
```

**The options:**

- --stat : show statistics
- hash: show all logs up to hash
- -1 : show only the latest log

Comment: through working a lot with git :) little by little you get to know its options and possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

The other answer is good if you're looking for the stats on a single change.

If you want to compare the tips of two branches, which I think is your real goal, you can use the same `--stat` option to `git diff` along with the [`..` syntax](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_ranges):

> To exclude commits reachable from a commit, a prefix `^` notation is used. E.g. `^r1 r2` means commits reachable from `r2` but exclude the ones reachable from `r1`.
>
> This set operation appears so often that there is a shorthand for it. When you have two commits `r1` and `r2` (named according to the syntax explained in SPECIFYING REVISIONS above), you can ask for commits that are reachable from `r2` excluding those that are reachable from `r1` by `^r1 r2` and it can be written as `r1..r2`.

So

```
git diff --stat master..release1_TMA
```

will show the same kinds of per-file statistics discussed elsewhere, e.g.

```
ClaimCenter/modules/ant/INGCCBuild.xml                  | 7 ++++-
ClaimCenter/modules/ant/InstallDependencies.properties  | 14 +++
ClaimCenter/modules/ant/InstallDependencies.xml         | 19 +++
```

but it will show the differences between `master` and `release1_TMA`.

Comment: I also tried you solution but it will show all files in all commits. I just want to list changed files which are in commits on release1_TMA only. Of course these commits only appear in release1_TMA only not in master yet.

Comment: @Nathanphan This answer can work for you too; but between two commits on the same branch (or as long as there is a linear path between them)